# Class not found exception when using Aws sdk to download file from s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, classnotfoundexception

```
I'm using AWS sdk for downloading an object from S3.when i run the program,i keep getting Class not found errors:
```

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.Consts
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hhtp.params.BasicHttpParams
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager
    I've included aws-java-sdk 1.3.26 jar file and httpcore 4.1 and httpclient 4.2.1 jars in my application still i'm getting the errors. I've written the foll code in my program to download a file from amazon s3:

```
AWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
            credentials);
     AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(myCredentials);
     S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(bucket, key);
     InputStream is=object.getObjectContent()
```

Not able to resolve the errors. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try with httpclient 4.1.1.

4.2+ deprecates/changes some functions